# sending mail via node js in laravel application

Tags: node.js, laravel

problem with receiving data from application form to node js server, the data deont ap perea
my from . in blade.php

````
        var subject = $('#subject').val().trim();
        var email = $('#to-Email').val().trim();
        var body = $('#Email-body').val().trim();

        const data = {
            subject, email, body
        };

        $.post('/mail', data, () => {
            console.log('Server receive data');
        });
    });```

my node js server.js ```   var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
// var js = require('./send_mail');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/offer');

app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen('8000');

console.log('Your node server start successfully....');

exports = module.exports = app;
````

can anyone helps me
[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9soup.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that you have a problem identifying what and where are the routes. Remember that laravel application and node js have differents web servers, so be aware of the routes and port of each application.

I can give a clue. This is what you have in your node js

```
app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Then you are calling the route in the ajax (client side), but you are no indetifying the server and port of node js.

```
$.post('/mail', data, () => {
            console.log('Server receive data');
        });
```

Comment: so what's the solution? I cannot receive any data